# Can Visual Studio still optimize pre-compiled code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, optimization

Ok the best way to explain my question is trough 2 examples:

**Example 1:**

*You have made yourself a framework or an engine of some sort called MyLibrary and you have built is as a **.lib** with maximum optimization options.Now you include the headers and link the **.lib** in a new project called MyImplementation.The project uses most of MyLibrary's functionality and when you're done,you build the project(again with maximum optimization).*

**Example 2:**

*Again you have the same library,but instead of building it,you leave it **open sourced**.Then you make the same MyProject,you include the headers and you build MyProject with maximum optimization enabled.*

So,would **Example 2** run faster,since the compiler has access to the entire source code(framework/engine + the project you use it in)?

Comment: My guesstimate is this is pretty unlikely. As far as I know, optimisation is traditionally done on single compilation units (a single library usually consists of many of those), and doesn't take usage of code in a whole "project" into consideration at all. It's also possible to perform some optimisations at link time, but those would obviously consider all the code being linked into an executable, once again regardless of your project. (That said, I'm not a compiler expert, so take this with a grain of sand.)

Comment: Interprocedural optimization should take into account multiple compilation units,no?

Answer (score 2):

A static library is pre-compiled, which means any further optimization is dependent on the linker. These days there are big performance gains to be gained from the linker, but generally the best results come from profile guided optimization, which does require special compiler settings to bootstrap the profile. It is always preferable to open source the project (unless you are protecting intellectual property), because then the developers can compile the project for their platform and compiler, not to mention debugging is virtually impossible without source code.